# PHP page hangs on this block of code

Tags: php, json

Recently, with no changes to my code, my PHP page started to hang at a certain area. It generates all of the HTML on the page right before this line:

```
$tickerJSON = file_get_contents("http://mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php");
```

I commented out everything else and this is the cause of the error.

I know that that JSON url is valid and the array names are correct. I'm not sure where the problem is in this case. Any help?

Note: It doesn't display a partial or white page, it'll keep loading forever with no display output.

Comment: Do you have display_errors turned on in your php config?

Comment: Check, how many seconds took `file_get_contents` execution. Write `$starttime = microtime(1);` before that line and `print round(microtime(1)-$starttime,5);` after. And second argument for file_get_contents looks useless there.

Comment: You can also turn on the [error-reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) temporarily.

Comment: I have display_errors turned on, but the page doesn't load white, it just keeps trying to load forever.

Comment: Also, you can figure out where its stalling by trying a die('here'); preceding each line

Comment: are you on a shared host? they might have changed their fopen wrappers policy.

Comment: I'm on a VPS, what do you mean?

Comment: Why do you use true in second argument?

Comment: Are you able to fetch other URLs, like google.com?  If not, it's a problem particular to your host/server settings.  If you are able to fetch other URLs, then it's due to the specific request you're sending.  You might have to match up the headers precisely to avoid the host stalling

Comment: Can you add allow_url_fopen = On in your php.ini file if its not already present and retry?

Comment: @babonk - Other urls do not work, @genesis - No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

```
$tickerJSON = shell_exec('wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php');
```

---

The remote connection you do takes a very long time. You can go around with that providing a timeout value. If it takes too long, the function won't return any data but it wont hinder the script as well from continuing to run.

Next to that you need to set the user-agent:

```
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'timeout'=> 3, // 3 second timeout
    'user_agent'=> 'hashcash',
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "https://mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php";
$tickerJSON = file_get_contents($url, FALSE, $context);
```

Comment: Okay, than this really looks like a connection problem. Do you have curl available? Can you run tests by shell?

Comment: The server was able to wget the file perfectly, so it's a PHP problem somewhere, I think.

Comment: @Sennheiser: If wget works, then you find a command in my updated answer that should to the job for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the remote server appears to be purposely stall requests that don't send a user agent string. By default, PHP's user-agent string is blank.

Try adding this line directly above your call:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP/' . PHP_VERSION);
```

I've tested the above using this script and it worked great for me:

```
<?php

ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP/' . PHP_VERSION);

$tickerJSON = file_get_contents("http://mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php");

echo $tickerJSON;
```

Comment: Still seems to send the request forever.

Comment: @Sennheiser - On the same "server" (as in on the same computer that executing the PHP file), are you able to open the link in a browser and see it's content? They could have blocked your IP address if they're trying to restrict access to their content.

Comment: Yes, I can access the link fine from the server. It may be a problem with SSL, since wget spit out some SSL errors until I had it ignore SSL. Also, the URL is http but it resolves to https automatically in a browser. Perhaps that's the cause?

Comment: @Sennheiser - It could be but I can't replicate the problem. The code I've posted above solved the "loading forever" problem on my end. You could try replace the "http" with an "https" in the URL and see if that solves the problem. Their SSL certificate appears to be valid. If that doesn't work, can you post the `wget` output, including errors?

Comment: @Sennheiser - There's clearly nothing wrong there other than it saying that the certificate is for "www.mtgox.com" and you requested "mtgox.com". I read a comment you made that `file_get_contents` won't open any URLs. Is that right?